# Query DynamoDB from within AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Ive been looking around, and have not been able to find anywhere on the AWS console a place where i can query the tables i have created in DynamoDB.

Is it possible for me to run quick queries against any of the tables i have in DynamoDB from within AWS itself.  Or will i actually have to go ahead and build a quick app that lets me run the queries??

I would have thought that there would be some basic tool provided that lets me run queries against the tables. If there is, its well hidden....

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DynamoDB console** -> **Tables** -> click the table you want to query -> select the **Items** tab

You will then see an interface to Scan or Query the table. You can change the first drop-down from "Scan" to "Query" based on what you want to do, and change the second drop-down to select the table index you want to query.

Comment: Thanks for that. Couldn't find this in any of the documentation they provided